# Attempting to create a pointer to previous object inside object

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to create a vector of pointers to Nodes, where each node stores a pointer to the previous Node in the list.

I made a small test program to see if I could access a variable gscore in the previous object to the one I call.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    Node(int gscore1)
    {
        gscore = gscore1;
    }

    Node *previous;
    int gscore;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Node*> nodeVec;

    Node *tempnode;
    tempnode = new Node(10);
    Node *tempnode2;
    tempnode = new Node(11);

    nodeVec.push_back(tempnode);
    nodeVec.push_back(tempnode2);

    nodeVec[1]->previous = tempnode;

    cout << nodeVec[1]->previous->gscore << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However this results in a crash. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: In the Node constructor, it'd be a good idea to initialize previous to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize tempnode2.  You initialize tempnode twice.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Node*> nodeVec;

    Node *tempnode;
    tempnode = new Node(10);
    Node *tempnode2;
    tempnode2 = new Node(11); // <<---- HERE

    nodeVec.push_back(tempnode);
    nodeVec.push_back(tempnode2);

    nodeVec[1]->previous = tempnode;

    cout << nodeVec[1]->previous->gscore << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that after staring at it for so long, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typing error. The third line in main() should be tempnode2 not tempnode.